# findstr: combine 2 commands

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I use `findstr` to search for files that contain random filename including 9 or 10 random digits and a random file extension.

I have the following files in my test directory:

```
ABCD142359865.pdf
EDFGH9658798563.docx
ZdgBE158795832.sql
GHrK147859632.mdb
!!!!!789548796.eml
XGU125965879.jpg
```

And I have the following line to pass directly to cmd :

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN ('dir /a-d /b /s "%~dp0" ^| findstr /i /r "[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\."') DO del /a /q "%%~A"

FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN ('dir /a-d /b /s "%~dp0" ^| findstr /i /r "[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\."') DO del /a /q "%%~A"
```

It is working as expected but is it possible to combine these 2 commands into one ?

Comment: Not necessary. All filenames that terminate with 10 digits must also terminate with 9 digits.

Comment: @Magoo is right - unless you want to keep files that terminate with 11 or more digits.

Answer (score 0):

Based upon your body text and shown examples I'd offer the following suggestion:

```bash
@For /F "EOL=? Delims=" %%G In ('Dir /A:-D-L /B /S ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R /C:"[^\\0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789]\.[^\.][^\.]*$" /C:"[^\\0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789]\.[^\.][^\.]*$"') Do @Del /A /F "%%G" 2>NUL
```

The above should pass all files which have an extension of one or more non period characters, and whose basename ends with any non digit character followed by a sequence of **only** nine or ten digit characters to the `Do` command.

As per your commented request, to ensure that the filenames have an extension of one or more non period characters, and a basename made up only from a sequence of one or nore English alphabet characters or exclamation points, followed by a sequence of only nine or ten digit characters, you could try:

```bash
@For /F "EOL=? Delims=" %%G In ('Dir /A:-D-L /B /S ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R /C:"\\[a-Z!][a-Z!]*[0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789]\.[^\.][^\.]*$" /C:"\\[a-Z!][a-Z!]*[0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789]\.[^\.][^\.]*$"') Do @Del /A /F "%%G" 2>NUL
```

Please note, in this latter version you should ensure that delayed variable expansion is not enabled.

---

*For testing you may wish to change `@Del /A /F "%%G" 2>NUL` to `@Echo Del /A /F "%%G" 2>NUL`*

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is it possible that the non-digital characters in the basename are only composed of letters and the character "!" ?

Comment: I have added an additional example to hopefully cater for your above comment.

Comment: Thank you ! What does the \\ before [a-Z!] mean ?

Comment: Because I'm matching a leaf of a fully qualified absolute path, I wanted to specify the backward slash which must precede any string of one or more alphabet characters, _(to prevent strings like `5aBc!0123456789`)_. The backward slash is a literal escape character for `findstr` regular expressions, so I needed two for a single literal one, _(e.g. `\aBc!0123456789`)_.